# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on Ubuntu Webserver, regardless of Access-Control-Allow-Origin Headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, web-development-server, ubuntu-server

the following problem. I have an Ubuntu web server running a React app. In particular, there are two files in the server file that process the requests made by the website. For some reason, however, it is not possible to make a request to the server as a client.

#### Server.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const mysql = require('mysql')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express()
app.use(cors({
    origin: ['*']
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '192.168.178.70',
    user: 'webserver',
    password: '123',
    database: 'lanparty',
    port: '3306'
})


app.get('/Ergebnisse', (req, res) => {
    console.log("gotRequest")

    db.query("SELECT * FROM lanparty.match;", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.json(err)
        } else {
            res.json(data)
        }  
    })
})


app.listen(30100, () => {
    console.log("Listening....")
})
```

#### Results.js:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import axios from "axios";

export default function Results() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("fetching...")
    axios.get('http://localhost:30100/Results')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log("data")
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:")
        console.log(error)
      });

  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="pageDiv">

      <h2>Results</h2>

    </div>
  );
}
```

If I´m making the request directly in the browser ( http://192.168.178.70:30100/Results ) everything works fine, so the server.js  should work, but the Request gets blocked if the webserver is the origin.The exact error looks like this:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:30100/Results. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

The request in the dev tools looks like this:
[description of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrJQv.png)

I tried literally every way of adding the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header:

- The way you see in my code right now
- The way you see in my code right now, but with every possibility to represent localhost ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', the ip address of the webserver)
- In my app.get, in the form of `res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost");`
  again I tried "*" and "127.0.0.1"

but non of these worked for me.

Thank you in advance for your time and help :)

Comment: `description of the error` - the **response** headers would be of more use

Comment: What do you mean by "if the webserver is the origin"?

Comment: "Status code: (null)"  seems like the request didn't return at all (timeout, ...) Have a look in the developer tools and check the `OPTIONS` request. Also try exectuting an `OPTIONS` request from like Postman ...

Comment: Different ports are considered different origin. First relax all the conditions and set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*`. Verify that this works. Then change localhost to `http://localhost:30100`. Additionally if you are using Nginx reverse proxy make sure these are not filtered out on the way to the client

Comment: @JaromandaX thats exactly my Problem, there is no response header

Comment: @derpirscher i mean the result.js. If the requst is coming from the webserver itself its not working, but if i try to fetch the data maually via the browser, its working

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin adding the header changes nothing, because the server isn´t even sending any result

Comment: Your server is on another machine as far as I understand, and you are checking the result from the browser from another machine. Check your reverse proxy settings IP mask to see what is permitted as proxypass and what is not.

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin yeah the server is another machine, and request from port 3000 (react app) to port 30100 (server.js) are not working. But requesting from my PC somehow works

Comment: You haven't cleary responded to this yet, are you using a reverse proxy such as Nginx? If yes can you share the config.

Comment: *"he server isn´t even sending any result"* Then this isn't a CORS issue.

Comment: @gre_gor Well I thought that cors is also responsible for checking the request before they get to the server? And the error message clearly states that it is an cors error

Comment: Firefox throws a CORS error even if the request wasn't even returned at all.

Comment: And if you access your site on `http://192.168.178.70:30100`, why are you making an AJAX request to `http://localhost:30100`? Is the server even on the same computer as the browser?

Comment: @gre_gor waiit, I thought that the result.js runs on the server (.70) just like the server.js. Is the result.js running on the client or the server? I thought it would run on the server, thats why I fetched on localhost

Comment: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429)

Comment: @gre_gor i guess that means yes.. I just thought that since I host the react app on the server the js would be executed on the server aswell.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know Node.js but I think I know what your are missing here: you didn't configure your server to response to preflight request.

Basically, when client (Results.js) code try to make a CORS request, the browser will fire a preflight request first. The purpose of this request is to verify that your server support CORS as well as which method/origin it supports.

1. Response to preflight request:

- Preflight request is a request with the same URL as CORS request, but method = OPTION
- You need to response to any request with method = "OPTION" with below headers:

  - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  - Access-Control-Allow-Methods: which method you allow for this resource, in your case "GET"
  - Access-Control-Allow-Headers: which headers you allow in the CORS request, as the above answer: "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json,Authorization"

2. Response to the main CORS request:

- After the preflight request success, browser will then fire your request in client.js.
- The response to this request also need to have the same headers as preflight request

***Note:*** Some browser may require additional headers for it to accept the CORS request. Just read the console log and add proper headers to the response
For your reference: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-responses

Comment: Sounds promising, but tbh I don´t know how to realize your suggestion. _(to 1:)_ Do you mean i should make another axios request before the actual .get ? _(to 2:)_ like i did in the first place with `res.addHeader()` ?

Comment: Preflight requests are only for complex CORS requests and OP's request doesn't seem to be and shows no CORS preflight request failure.

Comment: @LeonOhneH 1. No, the browser will do that for you, you just need to change your server.js to response to preflight request. 2. Yes

Comment: @gre_gor As I know preflight request is automatically send by the browser, and it doesn't matter if your request is complex or not. Please correct me if I'm wrong. And by which criteria that you define if a request is complex or not? A request is a request, and how there can be a request that is "complex" than another one?

Comment: ["It appears when request is qualified as "to be preflighted" and omitted for simple requests."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

Comment: And OP is not getting any response at all. Setting up preflight won't fix that.

Answer (score -2):

**I had a problem once, mostly it is an error caused if Firefox browsers. there might be an issue in the header or the client or in the server**

### List of solutions

1. setting the header in the server

```
// set the headers 
app.use(function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5173");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json,Authorization",
  );
  next();
});

// initialize cors 
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "http://localhost:5173" : process.env.HOST as string}));
```

as you can see i use two layers of setting cors

1. manually setting the headers
2. using the cors middlewares.

this works when using HTTP clients and and sometimes still fail on using it in the browser

2. setting the headers in the client since you are using axios.

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const config = {
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000',
  withCredentials: 'include',
  timeout: 8000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
  },
};

export const api = create(config);
export default api;
```

Sometimes the browser will intentionally fail your request especially when dealing with request like **PUT Requests** because of some browsers built in security features.

Comment: Setting CORS header on the request from browser to server is utterly nonsense ...

Comment: If CORS middleware isn't working, why would manually setting the headers work?

Comment: it says the cors is not successful when I that problem is either being blocked by the browser because the server is not supporting preflight. I encounter this error often, and often times it's not the servers fault it can be some browser extenuation is causing the error.